# How to open a hyperlink in the same tab using a keyboard shortcut

Tags: google-sheets, keyboard-shortcuts, links

How do you open a hyperlink in Google Sheets using only keyboard shortcuts? Google has <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> which opens the hyperlink, but in a new tab in Chrome. How can you open the hyperlink using only keyboard shortcuts so the hyperlink opens in the current tab of Chrome on Windows?

My hyperlinks link to another cell within the same Google Sheet, just on another tab. For example:

```
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(B4)),HYPERLINK("#gid=1234567892range="&"A"&MIN(ArrayFormula(IF(Projects!A:A=B4,ROW(Projects!A:A),""))),"Link"),"")
```

I don't want to keep re-opening the same Google Sheet in multiple tabs.

Comment: Welcome. Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and maybe [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can you open the hyperlink **using only keyboard shortcuts** so
>   the **hyperlink opens in the current tab** of Chrome on Windows?

**You can not**.

It has nothing to do with the browser. Google has it that by default all links in spreadsheets open in either a new Tab or a window, depending on how you have set up your browser.
But there is no way you can open them within the same tab or window. And most certainly there is no shortcut.

**EDIT** *([as reminded](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/134996/google-sheets-keyboard-shortcut-open-a-hyperlink-in-the-same-tab/134997#comment123466_134997) by Ken)*

> If I hover over the cell, and click the hyperlink that "pops up" over
>   that cell, it does open in the current tab. It just navigates me over
>   to that cell on that referenced sheet. That works great. But no
>   keyboard shortcut to do the same? Bummer :/

Comment: If I hover over the cell, and click the hyperlink that "pops up" over that cell, it does open in the current tab. It just navigates me over to that cell on that referenced sheet. That works great. But no keyboard shortcut to do the same? Bummer :/

Comment: _"Bummer :/"_ and there is nothing you can do about it. Also. I believe I should add your clarification on the answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's not as good as a single keyboard shortcut, but I have found that if I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, it will open the link in the same tab.